# xml as method's result in client-server application vs web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, web-applications

Dears, kindly note that I wand to develop a web application or client-server application,
I want my client to call methods on server side, some of those methods return XML data, would you advice me from where to start?
if I want to use windows form client server application, I think the only way to call server's method is by using .net remoting technique , but I'm not sure if it is possible to return XML files in this way?
so, what if I use web application, also is it easy to return XML data for some server method,

sorry, I am new in programming world

Answer (score 0):

Web API will return XML or JSON by default, depending on what the request from your application wants, and indicates in it's "accept header".

If you want to return only XML you can change the set up so that only XML is returned.

There is lots of information [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview), especially the section "[Serialization and Model Binding](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding)"

Working with it here, we do not specify accept headers, or change the default formatters and just let it do it's thing, and it works great.